# Solve $a^b - b^a = 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponentiation

For all positive integers $a,b$, given $a^b - b^a = 3$ Find all possible values of $a$ and $b$

I tried to simulate this using a program and found the one fit $a = 4$ and $b = 1$.  Would love to see a Mathematical solution for it.  Please help.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, the only integer solutions are $a=4, b=1$ and $a=1, b=-2$. Not sure how to go about proving that though

Comment: Positive integers  so a=4 and b=1 seems to be the only fit

Comment: My mistake not sure how I glossed over that positive integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find integral solution of $a^{b} - b^{a} = 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065448/find-integral-solution-of-ab-ba-3) and [Find all solutions in positive integers to $a^b -b^a = 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195113/find-all-solutions-in-positive-integers-to-ab-ba-3)